# how to handle different screen sizes in react native?

Tags: user-interface, react-native, screen-size

I am developing an application on react-native. I have made a UI which works fine on iPhone 6 but not working fine on iPhone 5 or lower versions. 
How should I fix this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you designed the app using fixed widths and heights? You should definitely use the capabilities of flexbox and try to avoid settings fixed sizes as much as possible. The [flex property](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flex) can be used to define how much space a `<View />` should use releative to others, and the other properties on that page can be used to lay out elements in a flexible way that should give the desired results on a range of different screen sizes.

Sometimes, you may also need a [`<ScrollView />`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html).

When you do need fixed sizes, you could use `Dimensions.get('window')`.

Answer (score 28):

You need to think about **proportion** when building your UI.

**1, Use `percentage(%)` for width and `aspectRatio` for height, or vice versa.**

```
container: {
    width: "100%",
    aspectRatio: 10 / 3, //height will be "30%" of your width
}
```

**2, Use flex for the jobs percentage can't do.** For example, if you have arbitrary size of items in a list and you want them to share equal sizes. Assign each of them with `flex: 1`

**3,** **Use `rem` from EStyleSheet instead of pixels**. `rem` **is a scale fator**. For example, if your `rem` is 2 and your “11rem” will become “11*2” = “22”. If we make `rem` proportion to the screen sizes, your UI will scale with any screen sizes.

```
//we define rem equals to the entireScreenWidth / 380
const entireScreenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
EStyleSheet.build({$rem: entireScreenWidth / 380});

//how to use rem
container: {
    width: "100%",
    aspectRatio: 10 / 3, //height will be "30%"
    padding: "8rem", //it'll scale depend on the screen sizes.
}
```

**4, Use scrollView for contents that could potentially scale out of the boxes.** For example, a `TextView`

**5, Every time you think about using pixels, consider use `rem` in method 3.**

For a detailed explanation, you can read the article here. [7 Tips to Develop React Native UIs For All Screen Sizes](https://medium.com/@shanerudolfworktive/7-tips-to-develop-react-native-uis-for-all-screen-sizes-7ec5271be25c)

Comment: Aspect Ratio messed everything up on my app. I don't know why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You need to calculate sizes dynamically, relying on screen size.

```
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

[...]

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')

[...]

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1.
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    myView: {
        width: width * 0.8, // 80% of screen's width
        height: height * 0.2 // 20% of screen's height
    }
})
```

If you are using `TabbarIOS`, remember that `Dimensions.get('window')` gives you the **whole** screen's height, this means that you'll have to take in account that the tabbar has fixed-height of 56.
So for example, when using `TabbarIOS`:

```
const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width,
      HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height - 56
```

Then use WIDTH and HEIGHT as above.

Comment: This does not work for multiple devices (it is actual not precise )

Comment: Where have you seen this not work?  It seems to be working well for me (at least on android)

Comment: On android @Philberg. Different appearance on my emulator and different appearances on real devices.